Motivation behind the defination of scalar multiplication of a Vectorspace over a field
In school, we studied physical notations, such as forces, velocities, and accelerations involving both magnitude and direction. We also called any such entity involving magnitude and direction a "vector". There, we learned about vector addition and scalar multiplication.
But in the abstract sense, we are saying $(V,+,*)$ is a vector space under a field $\Bbb F$ if it satisfies some specific properties.  Like in our above example, $V = \Bbb R^{n}$ and $\Bbb F = \Bbb R$.
Questions:


I want to know the motivation behind defining a scalar multiplication like $*: \Bbb F \times V \to V$. What is the need to specify an extra set $\Bbb F$? I mean, is it not always possible to define vector multiplication?
For example, if $(R, +,*)$ is a ring, we can define ring multiplication like $*: R \times R \to R$.
Is it only the abstract definition of vectors with magnitude and direction? Because if $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space, then it is isomorphic to $\Bbb F^n$, so if we assume $V = \Bbb F^n$, then we don't need this scalar multiplication, we can define only ring multiplication $*:\Bbb F^n \times \Bbb F^n \to \Bbb F^n$.



For example, if $$ is the scalar multiplication operation on $\mathbb R^3$, then $(5, (1,2,3)) = (5, 10, 15)$. The function $$ takes two inputs: a scalar and a vector. So $: \mathbb R \times \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^3$.

No, that is not my point; why scalar multiplication is needed? What is the motivation behind it? I have written that in my question. Is there any mathematical motivation, or is it only an Abstract definition of  vectors that we all studied in physics?

The scalar multiplication is needed, because we don't want to consider $(V,+)$ as abelian group alone. Then a space generated by $v$ would only contain sums of  $v$ and $-v$, and nothing like $\frac{1}{2}v$. So we want to consider $V$ as a $K$-module over a field $K$.
